# Error when using a custom caption with longtable in LaTeX

Tags: captions, longtable, renewcommand

I'm having trouble defining a custom caption for a longtable environment in LaTeX. The custom caption works fine for normal tables, but when I try to use it with longtable, I encounter an error. Strangely, the issue does not seem to be related to the \ in the custom caption. I already read about line breaks in longtable captions, but as you see when I do the caption manually it works.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\customcaption}[2][]{%
  \caption[#1]{\textbf{#1} \\ #2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
\caption[Works]{\textbf{Works} \\ Bar} \\
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{lll}
\customcaption[Not working]{Bar} \\
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The first longtable with a regular caption works fine. However, when I try to use the custom caption defined by \customcaption for the second longtable, it produces the following error:

```
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
! Misplaced \noalign.
\caption ->\noalign 
                    \bgroup \@ifnextchar [{\egroup \LT@c@ption \@firstofone ...
l.43 \customcaption[Foo]{Bar}
                              \\
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
...
```

The issue seems to arise from the \newcommand and not really the linebreak within it (It also fails without the linebreak). I guess it is because longtable somehow reimplements `caption`. Perhaps I can at least create a special longtable customcaption separately?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: the caption in longtable is at the core a \multicolumn and need to be at the begin of a cell. That no longers works if you are hiding that inside an unexpandable commands. Try `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\customcaption}{O{}m}{\caption[#1]{\textbf{#1} \\ #2}}`

Comment: Amazing Ulrike. Thank you so much! This worked like charm. I was fiddling with this for hours. After years of using latex, all this very special commands are magic to me.